# SweetAlert Not allowing user to interact

Tags: jquery, sweetalert

I am using [SweetAlert.js](http://tristanedwards.me/sweetalert) to replace the typical `alert();` function. There's an issue with the firing order, and I can't get it to stay after the user has tried submitting an incomplete form. In "show" mode on jsFiddle, the alert fires on page load. In the actual page I have it setup on, it doesn't fire at all, but the text of the alert shows at the bottom of the page.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/d8s7rm19/1/

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
if ('localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null) {
    try {
        //Get stored data
        var users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'));

        if (users === null) {
            //If no stored data, create empty array
            //users = [];
            sweetAlert("Oops...", "Something went wrong!", "error");
        }

        //Create new user entry
        user = {
            name: $(".name").val(),
            phone: $(".phone").val(),
            website: $(".website").val(),
            contact: $(".contact").val()
        };

        //Add new entry to stored array
        users.push(user);

        //Save array
        localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(users));

        alert("The data was saved.");
        return true;

    } catch (e) {
        if (e == QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR) {
            alert('Quota exceeded!');
        }
    }
    } else {
        alert('Cannot store user preferences as your browser do not support local storage');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the link event from processing. In this case, use:

```
event.preventDefault()
// and
return false;
```

See the updated solution: http://jsfiddle.net/d8s7rm19/2/